# "Не нужной": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не

Как в данном предложении пишется "не нужной": слитно или раздельно?

> Получать 90% **не нужной** тебе информации

Answer (score 1):

*Получать 90% **ненужной** тебе информации.*

НЕНУЖНЫЙ,  1. Такой, в котором нет нужды, необходимости, действительной потребности; лишний, **бесполезный**.

1) Здесь нет отрицания, можно заменить **синонимом без НЕ**.

2) Зависимые слова **не влияют** на написание прилагательных с НЕ.

3) Раздельное написание встречается **при усилении** отрицания.

...он умный человек, но ум его ледяной, **никому не нужный**. [Юрий Трифонов. (1976)]